# How do I use a library in PineScript to access a value?

Tags: pine-script, pine-script-v5, tradingview-api, pine-script-v4

I have calculated a value in a library script, which is assigned to the variable "index".

Now I want to continue working with the value in an indicator script and mark with plotshape when the value exceeds a certain size.

However, I am not familiar with libraries.
I managed to import the library into my indicator script.
However, despite using the plotshape function correctly, it shows me nothing in the chart. But I don't get an error message either.
Therefore I think it could be because I didn't declare the export function correctly.

```
export indi(int index) =>
    index
```

As I said in the variable index (integer) is the value I want to work with.

Did I define correctly that I want to export the variable "index"? Or do you detect another error?

Comment: This should help
https://www.tradingview.com/pine-script-docs/en/v5/concepts/Libraries.html

Comment: We can remove a bunch of tags from the post. Libraries aren't available in Pine v4. Pine-Script is too broad, and TradingView API is just for their own API, I presume.